# Reversing a hash preserving Duplicate values

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, hashtable, associative-array

My existing hash is

```
my $volvg = {
        'datavol' => 'oradatavg',
        'archvol' => 'archvg',
        'archvol1' => 'archvg',
        'soevol' => 'soevg',
        'redovol' => 'oradatavg'
};
```

I want to reverse the hash in following way

```
 $vgvol = { 'oradatavg' => [
                  'datavol',
                  'redovol'
                ], 'archvg' =>    [ 
                  'archvol',
                  'archvol1
                ] 'soevg' =>     [
                  'soevol'
                ] };
```

Can someone help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: You should show some of the work you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Reversing in-place is probably a bad idea, create a new hash, and then if you need assign it to the old one.

Below is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $volvg = {
        'datavol' => 'oradatavg',
        'archvol' => 'archvg',
        'archvol1' => 'archvg',
        'soevol' => 'soevg',
        'redovol' => 'oradatavg'
};


my $reversed;
while( my( $k, $v)= each %$volvg)
  { # $reversed->{$v}||=[];   # not needed, see dgw's comment below
    push @{$reversed->{$v}}, $k; # push the old key into the array
  }

use DDP; p $reversed; # for checking the result
                      # you can also use Data::Dumper or other modules
```

Comment: Due to autovivification there is no need to initialize the array before pushing onto it.

Comment: darn, you're right! Thanks. I always assumed that autovivification worked for "regular" scalars, but you needed to be explicit if you wanted a reference. My bad. And I've learned something.

Answer (score 1):

What's a little unclear in Perl, is how to embed arrays into hashes. Because pretty fundamentally - you can't. There's no such thing as a hash of arrays.

But what there is, is a hash of array *references*. You can manipulate an array ref like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper; 

my $array_ref = [ "one", "two" ]; 
print Dumper \$array_ref;

push ( @$array_ref, "three-ish" );
print Dumper \$array_ref;

my $hash_ref; 
$hash_ref->{"carrot"} = $array_ref; 
print Dumper \$hash_ref; 

push ( @{$hash_ref->{"carrot"}}, "a new value" );
print Dumper \$hash_ref;
```

So hopefully you can see the basis of what you need for creating the data structure you're looking for. Either extract the values and keys you want, create an array ref and insert them into a hash. Or iterate, and use push.

Comment: Good answer. Important to point out the need for **references** in nested data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Inverting a hash is a classic question/recipe from the [Perl Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003135.do). The solution is trivial when the values being inverted into keys are unique.

```
%rev_hash  = reverse %hash ;
```

but, as you note, that's not often the case thus the explanations/solutions offered in other answers here are necessary. Once you understand references it's not too hard (++ @Sobrique for making this link).

The Cookbook and other perl resources sometimes recommend `tie`-ing the hash  (*e.g.* *c.f* [`Tie::RefHash`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::RefHash)) to make working with the references easier.

If you are inverting a hash that itself contains references it can tricky if you have to go deep into the hash. Here's a simple example that should invert a hash that has an array reference as a value.

```
use DDP;

my $volvg = {
  'datavol' => ['oradatavg', 'oradatavgpoo2'] ,
  'archvol' => 'archvg', 
  'archvol1' => 'archvg',
  'soevol' => 'soevg',
  'redovol' => 'oradatavg' };

while ( ($k,$v) = each(%$volvg) ) {  
   if (ref $v) { 
     map { push @{$volvg_rev{$_}}, $k }  @$v ;
   }  
   else { 
     push @{$volvg_rev{$v}}, $k  ;   
   } 
}

p $volvg ;
print "----\n";
p %volvg_rev ;
```

**Output**:

```
  \ {
    archvol    "archvg",
    archvol1   "archvg",
    datavol    [
        [0] "oradatavg",
        [1] "oradatavgpoo2"
    ],
    redovol    "oradatavg",
    soevol     "soevg"
}
----
{
    archvg          [
        [0] "archvol1",
        [1] "archvol"
    ],
    oradatavg       [
        [0] "redovol",
        [1] "datavol"
    ],
    oradatavgpoo2   [
        [0] "datavol"
    ],
    soevg           [
        [0] "soevol"
    ]
}
```

---

As an aside, Perl6 has some [neat new methods](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/different-names-of-different-things/) for `reverse`-ing, `invert`ing and `flip`ping things around.